# If on Category Page add "active" class?

Tags: categories

I am trying to register an "active" class on my `li` if the category matches the page. If you click the `horror` category it will show you a loop with all the videos in that category. But the button for `horror` does not show an active class. I know I need an `if else` statement but the things I have tried simply do not work and break the site. Im not good enough with PHP or Wordpress to really figure this out.

Site here

**CATEGORY.PHP**

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent' => 0
        );
      $categories = get_categories( $args );
      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<li> <a class="browse-categories" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a> </li>';
}
```

**Can something like this do the trick?**

```
if ( $category->slug == $category->term_id )
```

Comment: you're only populating `$post_cats` if you're on a category page, and you're only trying to compare each category ID to the post's categories if you're on a single post, those two conditions will never align.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im still new to Wordpress. I see what you are saying, a lot of what I have done thus far is kind of stumbled upon in the first place. 1. Is there a better way to write this, if so then how? And 2. How can I get them to align to write a proper `if else` function?

Comment: See updated post